# What's the meaning of "is there any other way to see it?"

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

> A: Are you saying accepting your help obligates me?
>
> B: **ls there any other way to see it?**
>
> A: No.

I found this line from the movie, As Good As It Gets, and I'm curious about this phrase **"Is there any other way to see it"**.

Does it mean 'please don't distort my intention. Please see it in other ways'?

Comment: B is saying "Not only am I not helping you for free, as far as I'm concerned 'free' doesn't exist."

Answer (score 1):

As always, context is everything.  "A" here is the character Carol Connelly (Helen Hunt), and "B" is the character Melvin Udall (Jack Nicholson) in the film *As Good As It Gets*.  Udall is an obsessive compulsive whose mental problems have stunted him emotionally, making it impossible for him to relate to other people.

When Carol asks Melvin whether her accepting his help obligates her, she's being incredulous.  In normal human interaction, people often offer their help to others freely.  But Melvin, not having normal emotional capacity, not only thinks that Carol's accepting his help obligates her to him, he can't think of any other possibility.